# Is .net app.config bindingRedirect dangerous?

Tags: .net, conflict

I see bindingRedirects all the time in different projects! For instance when creating a new MVC5 project.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

People uses it to solve all kind of version conflicts, without thinking much about it.

- Isn't this dangerous, leading to runtime error?
- Why would Microsoft create redirects between mayor version, when the API probably has changed?
- Could the compiler check that the API hasn't changed?

Also, even when the API is unchanged the logic could have changed.

Comment: This is a really good question.  I have no idea why people do binding redirects and assume there will be no problems switching between library versions.  It's a shame no-one answered it.